# Alien, Middle Ages, Norman Knight

Tags: story-identification, novel

Novel from the late '80s - early '90s. Can't remember much about it - didn't finish it. About a humanoid (Alien? Time traveler? Can't remember) who visits Earth in the Middle Ages & gets involved with two people. One of them is a Norman knight who tries to take advantage of the traveler's advanced technology to defeat his enemies.

Comment: Might it have been a Spanish knight?  I recall a story with a Spanish knight in Anderson's Time Patrol series that seems very similar, though that work is a collection of short-story or novella length stories (though interrelated enough it can be read as a very episodic work), rather than a coherent novel.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it turns out I can answer my own question - the book is 'Fanglith' by John Dalmas.

Comment: I'm glad you found it, it sounds pretty neat :)  You can, if you want, post your own answer so anyone else looking can find it easier (also I think you might get a badge from self-answering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the OP's comment above, this was *[Fanglith](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2536264.Fanglith)* by John Dalmas, published 1985.

The Norman Knight angle is better covered in the sequel, *[Return to Fanglith](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3066432-return-to-fanglith)*:

[image: Return to Fanglith - book cover]

> The Federation: Oppressive, dictatorial, and merciless to all who oppose it, the Fedration has become an Empire - and imperial fleets are expanding its brutal dominion to the colony worlds. Those of the resistance movement not trapped in the first strike barely escape with their lives.
>   Larn and Dineen: Their deepest hope is to join the rebel forces. But the base is hidden well - and in the meantime the two must lie low. No one will look for them on a barbaric planet like Earth...
>   Arno of Courmeron: The Norman knight who captures them learns that plans and wealth can be wiped out by the unpredictable...and that blood enemies may become blood brothers.

Comment: Mind adding some explanation so that it's more helpful for future visitors?